# Themes in a styled based component library [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, themes, styled-components

This is more of a architectural question. Currently I have a components library that a user can use to build out their UI application.

The styled components in this component library are making use of themes to provide base structure/styling to the respective components.

This is the sample structure of component

```
src 
  -components
    - Overlay
       - Overlay.jsx
       - stories.jsx
       - themes.jsx
```

The contents of `themes.jsx`

```
import colors from theme/colors

export
  overLay:{
    default:{
       backgroundColor: "..."
       broderRadius: "..."
       .....
    }
  }
```

Currently this structure only supports one default theme file. But what about the use case where I need to support various theme files. For example with the Overlay, there is **product 1** that requires the default theme, but for **product 2** the Overlay has completely different theme definition.

What is the best way to serve this, if individual products were to import these components? Would you go about creating a base theme file, and then an overrides for the individual product?

Comment: Have you looked at [styled-theming](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-theming)?

Answer (score 0):

Depending what is needed to be changed in the second theme. You can either create an entire new theme object or you can override specific components. The last option can get a bit messy if the difference from the two theme will grow by time.

Here are is a neat example of having 2 different themes which differs just with the `overLay`

```
//themes.js

export const themeA = {
   ...,
  overLay:{
      backgroundColor: "red",
      broderRadius: "10px"
    }
}
export const themeB = {
    ...themeA,
     overLay:{
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        broderRadius: "2px"
    }
};
```

then

```
import { themeA, themeB } from 'path-to/themes.js`

<ThemeProvider theme={ condition ? themeA : themeB }>
```